# Read mulitiline JSON formatted data stored statically in a text file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, json.net

The JSON data mentioned above will not be fetched from a web service or any other source from the web.I would be manually creating a template and storing JSON formatted data, in a text file in my local machine.I have looked at JSON.net which contains useful methods to get the job done.The code I have used so far is  below and it prints appropriately

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
var data = w.DownloadString(@"D:\ComponentsJSON.txt");
//Read the file    
JObject j = JObject.Parse(data);
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + j["name"]);
Console.WriteLine("Property1: " + j["property"][0]);
Console.WriteLine("Property2: " + j["property"][1]);
```

But the above can read only a single line from the text file.When multiple Json elements are present in the same file, how could this be done.

The contents of  D:\ComponentsJSON.txt are :

```
[{"name":"WinWindow", "property" : ["Name","ClassName"], "value": ["MCP","OSCP"]},

{"name":"WinButton", "property" :["Name","ClassName"], "value": ["OK","Button"]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to narrow down the issue

Comment: Thanks for adding sample and actually adding the issue you are facing.

Comment: Note: it look like now title of your post have nothing to do with body of the post - you have code that parses correct JSON already and your question seem to be "how to parse multiple JSON objects piled into single file (possibly without any separators)". Consider adding very small sample that shows how you file actually look like (i.e. "{a:1}{a:2}" or "{a:1}\n{a:2}" or something else).

Comment: Why are you using WebClient to read a file?

Comment: You are right.I replaced WebClient with a simple StreamReader to get the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Parse` methods are for parsing specific objects, not deserializing an entire file. If the JSON contains an array you need to call JArray.Parse. JObject will parse a single object only.

To read an arbitrary string use one of the [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) overloads, eg:

```
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

or

```
var items=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(data);
```

Check  "[Serializing Collections](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html)" in Json.NET's documentation